# Routing not working when codeigniter in sub folder

Tags: codeigniter

My CodeIgniter code in a subdirectory, so only index page is working when I  hit any other request than it loading the parent folder index file.

**Structure is:**

> *Parent folder
>
>     index.php
>
>     sub folder / codeigniter set up*

I have tried the htaccess code and `request_uri` in config.

I want to hit all my Codeigniter URL properly. Because on any request it loading the parent folder index.php file content.

Comment: please read **[ask]**

Answer (score 0):

Please set your .htaccess to this

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

And in the config use this

```
$base  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $base;

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Hopefully it will work :)

Comment: No ,the issue is still exist

Comment: My php version is 5.3 and my codeigniter version is 3.1 so it be a reason for this ?

Comment: One more thing should i check for my rewrite module ,will it effect if is not enabled ?

Comment: Can you provide me your skype id so I can assist you?

Comment: hi my skype id is live:sandeep_2221

Answer (score 0):

in the config file set your base url to the hosting site

> $config['base_url'] = 'http://whateverthesitepathis';

then in the routes do this

> $route['default_controller'] = 'folder/controller';
>   $route['(:any)'] = 'folder/controller/$1';